# How to compare the layout of pdf files programmatically?

Tags: ruby, selenium, pdf, layout

It is possible to rip the text from pdf and comapre it. And here i need to compare if the layout of the pdf with another pdf file. Is it possible programmatically? There are third party tools to do that, but is it available for testing using selenium or any programming language?

I have gone through google, but couldn't find a solid solution for this yet? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing the layout"?

Comment: @mkl Need to verify the position/ indentation/ alignment of the text/ image/ lines in the pdf file. makes sense?

Comment: So would it suffice if you had a function that extracts all the text fragments with its position and orientation from a PDF? You could apply that function to both PDFs you want to compare and then actually compare these (text fragment, position, orientation) tuples.

Comment: @mkl most probably yes, also i wouldn't bother about the images for now.

Comment: Ok, creating such a function should be possible with any general purpose PDF library. It definitively is possible with the Java libraries iText, PDFBox, and PDF Clown, but as you removed the [tag:java] tag, that possibly won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

With [PDF Box](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) of apache you should be among other things be able to extract the text from existing PDF documents.

ps: you probably have to create a custom program in jave to extract and compare and invoke it from selinium.

Comment: I can extract the text, that is not the intention here. I need to compare the layout of the pdf file, is that possible?

Comment: Layout comparison won't be possible with PDF Box. There is however this extension [PDF Box Layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/wiki) that might be usefull.

Comment: This might also be interesting to look at: https://www.snowtide.com/help/3.3.1. It also has ways to guarantee the layout of extracted (see https://www.snowtide.com/help/3.3.1/controlling-formatting-extracted-text)